# C# .bat file execution with Error & Output redirection

Tags: c#, batch-file, exe

I have a .bat file to be executed.

Inside that `.bat` file, at its end is that code

```
START _file_creator.bat %some_arg_name%
ENDLOCAL
EXIT
```

I don't want to show the window during the execution and also I must wait until the operation doing by this `.bat` file is completed and then terminate the execution (at the end of the operation I see the standard text "Press any key to continue"). I need also to check the output and errors by that file, so I'm trying to use that code:

```
        System.Diagnostics.Process proc = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
        proc.StartInfo.FileName = @"C:\m_f\_config.bat";
        proc.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
        proc.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
        proc.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
        proc.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;

        proc.Start();
        proc.WaitForExit();
        output1 = proc.StandardError.ReadToEnd();
        proc.WaitForExit();
        output2 = proc.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
        proc.WaitForExit();
```

But all I get is the error

```
Windows can not find file "_file_creator.bat".
Make sure you typed the name correctly and try again.
```

of course if I run that `.bat` file with the `proc.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = true` it works fine, but in that case I can't set `RedirectStandardError = true` and `RedirectStandardOutput = true`

How to fix it ?

### Edit

using that code it works now

```
 proc.StartInfo.FileName = @"C:\m_f\_config.bat";
 proc.StartInfo.WorkingDirectory = @"C:\m_f\";
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try setting the working directory correctly or make sure that `_file_creator.bat` is somewhere in the `PATH`. See the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo.useshellexecute.aspx) about the working directory in conjunction with `UseShellExecute`:

> The [WorkingDirectory](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo.workingdirectory.aspx) property behaves differently depending on the value of the **UseShellExecute** property. When **UseShellExecute** is **true**, the [WorkingDirectory](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo.workingdirectory.aspx) property specifies the location of the executable. If [WorkingDirectory](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo.workingdirectory.aspx) is an empty string, it is assumed that the current directory contains the executable.
>
> When **UseShellExecute** is **false**, the [WorkingDirectory](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo.workingdirectory.aspx) property is not used to find the executable. Instead, it is used only by the process that is started and has meaning only within the context of the new process. When **UseShellExecute** is **false**, the [FileName](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo.filename.aspx) property must be a fully qualified path to the executable.

Comment: the _file_creator.bat file is in the same directory as the executed .bat file

Comment: That doesn't matter. The working directory is inherited from your C# program as the quote above shows. You have to set the working directory for the new process yourself for it to work.