# Running a .Bat in a C# form

Tags: c#, winapi, batch-file, cmd

My aim is to Execute an external .bat File from C#. The problem is that i have to Display the results of the executed Bats in my form, not in the Console. The solutions on google only show me how to start a bat, but not how to get the Contents from the Console.

**What could be the best way to realize this?**

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11177554/c-sharp-bat-file-execution-with-error-output-redirection

Comment: Doesnt help, i want to have the output the whole time, not just after its finishes. It has to update on each line that the bat generates

Comment: You can use proc.StandardOutput.ReadLine() instead of proc.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd() to read each line as it is output

Comment: That should help. I´ll try that and give respond if it worked

Comment: I will block waiting on that

Comment: Why would you want to display textual output on a form? It is not designed for that. Use a console window instead.

Comment: Because I have multiple very complex bats with a decent amount of outputs and i want to have all results at one place. Also, i need a possibility to export the data.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can use the StandartOutputEvent in the Process class:

```
    const string BATFILE = "Test.bat";
    const bool HIDE = true;
    static Encoding ENCODING = Encoding.Default;

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo psi = new System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo("cmd", BATFILE);

        if (HIDE)
        {
            psi.WindowStyle = System.Diagnostics.ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
        }

        psi.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
        psi.StandardOutputEncoding = ENCODING;
        psi.UseShellExecute = false;

        System.Diagnostics.Process p = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
        p.StartInfo = psi;
        p.OutputDataReceived += p_OutputDataReceived;

        p.Start();
    }

    static void p_OutputDataReceived(object sender, System.Diagnostics.DataReceivedEventArgs e)
    {
        //Do something with a form...
        System.Console.WriteLine(e.Data);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you need need this too :

```
...                 
psi.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
psi.RedirectStandardError = true;
...

p.Start();

p.checkoutProcess.BeginOutputReadLine();
p.checkoutProcess.BeginErrorReadLine();
```